# Routing Error: uninitialized constant UserFriendshipsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a Team Treehouse Ruby on Rails app that emulates a basic Facebook app.

I am now added social feature's like friends.

I recently added the following link to one of my views:

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", new_user_friendship_path(friend_id: @user), class: 'btn' %>
```

When click the resulting button, I get the following error:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant UserFriendshipsController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I am thinking the problem is in either my "user_friendship_controller.rb" of "config/routes.rb " file.

Here is my "user_friendship_controller.rb file:

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

  def new
    if params[:friend_id]
      @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:friend_id]).first
      @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Friend required"
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found
  end
end
```

And here is my "config/routes" file:

```
Treebook::Application.routes.draw do
  as :user do
    get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new',via: :get, as: :register
    get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new', via: :get, as: :login
    get '/logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', via: :delete, as: :logout
  end

  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]

  as :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
    delete '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :user_friendships do
  end

  resources :statuses
  get 'feed', to: 'statuses#index', as: :feed
  root to: 'statuses#index'

  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show', as: 'profile'
end
```

Any help figuring out this bug is a great help.

### Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's just a simple mis-naming of your file.

Try renaming it to `user_friendships_controller.rb`. Rails expects your class declaration to match the file name (as it stands it'd be looking for you to define `UserFriendshipController`).